# script fails with command not found

Tags: bash, unix

I have written simple script like this:

```
x=1
y=1

while ( $x eq "1" ) ||  ( $y eq "1" )
do 
 x=10
 echo "inside loop"
done
```

It is giving me below error:

```
sh-4.2$ bash -f main.sh                                                                         


    main.sh: line 8: 1: command not found                                                                                                                                    
    main.sh: line 8: 1: command not found
```

What is wrong with my script, how can I fix this?

Comment: As with learning any other language, you should read the documentation, instead of just writing what you think is valid syntax.

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking here for help. Also, the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) has many links to frequent beginner questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

x=1
y=1

while [ $x -eq "1" ] || [ $y -eq "1" ]
do
        x=10
        y=10
        echo "inside loop"
done
```

I think this may serve your purpose.

Answer (score -2):

At first you should try to use  [ ]

```
while [ $x eq "1" -o $y eq "1" ]
```

Comment: Its `-eq`, not just `eq`. Don't forget to quote `$x` when using the single `[`.

Comment: And don't use `-o`; use two separate test commands joined with `||`.